# Using a solid state relay/ photoMOS relay

Tags: solid-state-relay

I'm trying to use solid state relay (Panasonic's [AQY277](http://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/catalogues/downloads/photomos/ds_x615_en_aqy27.pdf) / [AQV215](http://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/catalogues/downloads/photomos/ds_x615_en_aqv21.pdf)) to switch a light bulb (100 V AC). To control the input, I'm using a signal generator in DC mode with 5 V as input. I have not yet succeeded in making it work. Anyone having any idea about wiring details of these relays?

Comment: do you have a wiring diagram ?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing exactly what you did.  You should be able to see for yourself we can't know what exactly you connected to what.

Comment: While I feel the question is vague, closing it just makes this forum discouraging for people trying to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have PIN 2 connected to the `GND` and `pin 1` to the driver among a 1.5K resistence ( that guarntee a correct current driving the internal LED ) of about `(5-1.2)/1.5K = 2.53 mA`  that according to the datasheet is enought to switch the device on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did this before as you suggested. I used a potentiometer (2K) but it didn't work. Is it possible that the signal generator is not able to sink enough current ?